# Can i install jython and normal django on same server

Tags: java, python, linux, jython

I have normal sites running with php and jango on my VPS.

Now i also want to try Jython. I want to know that can i install that on my same VPS server or i need to get new server for jython. WOn't the normal , python Django modules mix up with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was there something wrong with Jython Django?
[django project with jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/) &
[django jython project](http://packages.python.org/django-jython/)

Edit apologies links updated use link 2.

Comment: i already have 4 sites running with simple django now i want to setup new site in jython , i didn't want to touch ols sites so i was asking . your 2 links are same